# How to send Theme info from Native Android app to flutter module 'aar' module?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, aar

Right now , I am including my flutter module built into an `aar` file inside the android app.
as per this documentation : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup

Now , I wish to send theme info of my android app to the flutter module and want to access the color values of the theme items inside flutter. How do I achieve this ?

This is the activity tag I included in my manifests. Now I wish to use the styles in the `AppTheme` from within my FlutterActivity , How to do this ?

```
<activity
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            />
```